# Passing Null to MySql as a String

Tags: mysql

I have a String like this :

```
String s = "id:1, name:null , field3:null";
```

Now I want to pass those values and fields to an INSERT statement. field3 type is INT, so name field get updated as null because of being a VARCHAR but field3 gives an exception saying that
a wrong value for an INT field.

Is there any keyword or something that I can put as an sql field value which would be automatically taken as null ?

Comment: Could you please show the final INSERT statement? Does field3 accepts NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter table to accept **NULL** in field3, use below query

```
ALTER TABLE  `tableName` CHANGE  `field3`  `field3` INT( 11 ) NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is to not specify `field3` in the insert - just leave it out and mysql will assign a `null` to that column